# OpenGL Depth/Culling Issues

Tags: ios, opengl-es, blender

I'm working on an OpenGL app for the iPhone. I recently worked through [this tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/48293/how-to-export-blender-models-to-opengl-es-part-1) to create a .obj to primitive conversion tool, once it was complete, I dropped my vertex data into the tutorial project and got a rotating cube as expected. Afterwards I went to Blender and generated a torus to experiment with an object that had more vertices. Upon importing and running, I noticed that there were draw issues with front-facing triangles in the background being drawn over front-facing triangles in the foreground.

I already have GL_CULL_FACE and GL_DEPTH_TEST running and implemented, so this issue really puzzles me. Any help is greatly appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved! I forgot to set the depth format

```
 GLKView.drawableDepthFormat = GLKViewDrawableDepthFormat24;
```